# how can I express this equation in gnuplot?

Tags: expression, gnuplot

In gnuplot, how would I express something like this:

[image]

Comment: RTFM (`help operators`) and THEN perhaps tell us what you want to do with this inequation. gnuplot is no program to do symbolic math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To express inequality, we'll use the ternary operator, where (in pseudocode)

```
if CONDITION:
    DO_A
else:
    DO_B
```

is expressed as

```
CONDITION ? DO_A : DO_B
```

so in our case,

```
if a != x:
    f(x) = (a - x)**(0.04)
else:
    f(x) = 0
```

is expressed as

```
f(x,a) = (a != x) ? (a - x)**(0.04) : 0
```

Note that we are expressing the 25th-root, or n^(1/25), as n^(0.04).

Plotting this equation will look something like the following:

```
reset
f(x,y) = (y != x) ? (y - x)**(0.04) : 0
unset colorbox
set isosample 300, 300
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set title '(y - x)^{0.04} != 0'
set sample 300
set pm3d map
splot [-500:500] [-500:500] f(x,y)
```

which yields
[image: Gnuplot Output]

Another way to express this is to simply do

```
reset
f(x,y) = (y - x)**(0.04) != 0
unset colorbox
set isosample 300, 300
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set title '(y - x)^{0.04} != 0'
set sample 300
set pm3d map
splot [-500:500] [-500:500] f(x,y)
```

which yields 
[image]

In this second image, Gnuplot is plotting the imaginary part of the equation (i.e., when x > a).

Comment: This is a really solid answer, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @j0h No problem -- hope it helps!